# "Cannot run test (h_c: is_deeply($n, $s)) with active children at /usr/lib/perl5/5.18.2/Test/More.pm line 1020"

Tags: perl

Trying to convert some code from `use Test::more` to `use Test::Builder` I got this problem when trying to use `is_deeply` (perl 5.18.2):

> Cannot run test (h_c: is_deeply($n, $s)) with active children at /usr/lib/perl5/5.18.2/Test/More.pm line 1020

The manual for `Text::builder` states this example for `explain`:

> is_deeply($have, $want) || diag explain $have;

However `Test::Builder` does not have the `is_deeply` method, but `Test::More` has it (I used `use Test::More 'import' => [qw(is_deeply)];` to import only that).
Unfortunately when trying to use it from a sub-test (`$tb->child()`), the program dies with the message cited above.

Is there a way to use `is_deeply` in a sub-test?

Message from within the Perl debugger:

```text
Cannot run test (h_c: is_deeply($n, $s)) with active children at /usr/lib/perl5/5.18.2/Test/More.pm line 1020.
 at /usr/lib/perl5/5.18.2/Test/Builder.pm line 1969.
        Test::Builder::croak('Test::Builder=HASH(0x1b6e3c0)', 'Cannot run test (h_c: is_deeply($n, $s)) with active children') called at /usr/lib/perl5/5.18.2/Test/Builder.pm line 769
        Test::Builder::ok('Test::Builder=HASH(0x1b6e3c0)', 1, 'h_c: is_deeply($n, $s)') called at /usr/lib/perl5/5.18.2/Test/More.pm line 1020
        Test::More::is_deeply('HOTP::Core=ARRAY(0x31131c8)', 'HOTP::Core=ARRAY(0x310ab10)', 'h_c: is_deeply($n, $s)') called at otptest.pl line 96
```